# PHP : How can I synchronize one online sql database with another offline database?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, offline

Currently working on bus ticket booking site here I want to run this site offline when online server is not working due to internet problem or server error which often occurs. Now problem is when I run this site offline through xammp server how can I  find last insert bus ID from online server and how will online server know what is last offline bus_id .

Anyone can book ticket online but only one pc will handle offline site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert some communication between this servers if both are online. Or you use different ids for both servers (largs ids offlie / small ids online).

Comment: How can I insert some communication between online and offline server.

Comment: You could add a pages which shows the last inserted id. Both servers request this page from the other server and store this id (could be probably done before every insert).